# Local to Azure backup errors and question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, backup, ssms, azure

I am wanting to back up a local SQL Server 2016 database to Azure.
When I first started looking into it, I found this quote from the Azure usage calculator.
[image]

When I tried to set it up, all the instructions I find say to do it using blob storage, but I'm not sure if that's what I should be doing.

Also, when I tried to set it up using blob storage:

```
use [master]
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [ReportServerTempDB] TO  URL = N'https://myStore.blob.core.windows.net/myStore/ReportServerTempDB_backup_2022_11_14_110732_7019080.bak' WITH  CREDENTIAL = N'BackupCred' , NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'ReportServerTempDB_backup_2022_11_14_110732_7019080', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 3271, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "https://myStore.blob.core.windows.net/myStore/ReportServerTempDB_backup_2022_11_14_110955_2639556.bak:" Backup to URL received an exception from the remote endpoint. Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive..
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I've tried looking up solutions to this, but they seem to mostly involve upgrading to SQL Server 2019 or installing a patch, and I'm wondering if there is something I am missing.

Edit: New query:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [ReportServerTempDB] TO  URL = N'https://myStore.blob.core.windows.net/myStore/ReportServerTempDB_backup_2022_11_14_110955_2639556.bak' WITH  CREDENTIAL = N'BackupCred' , FORMAT,  NAME = N'ReportServerTempDB_backup_2022_11_14_110955_2639556',  STATS = 10
```

Comment: from my past experience, `WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT` in BACKUP command won't work when backing up to Azure blob storage (`TO URL`);  try removing `NOFORMAT, NOINIT`, add `WITH FORMAT` - and see if that fixes the error.  If that works, let me know and I will post this comment as an answer

Comment: also, remove SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD options

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko I removed those bits and got the same error. I also removed the STATS 10 just to be sure, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: basically the command should look like this:  `BACKUP DATABASE [ReportServerTempDB] TO  URL = N'https://myStore.blob.core.windows.net/myStore/ReportServerTempDB_backup_2022_11_14_110732_7019080.bak' WITH  CREDENTIAL = N'BackupCred' , FORMAT,   STATS = 10`  and make sure the credential has been properly created on a SQL Server

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko Still running into that same error, and so I'm going to test backing up from SQL2019 to make sure version is not the problem. But I'm curious, is blob storage actually the best way to do it? If my full backup is 9 GB, and I'm uploading a full backup once a week, and pushing differential backups a few times a day, it seems like it's going to just take up a lot of space over time. Is this really the best way to handle it?